# Set BarButtonItem directly from navigation controller

Tags: swift, swift2

I have navigation controller with one rootViewController called "LoginController". When I try to add rightBarButtonItem from init of LoginController so it works, but directly in navigation controller same operation does not works.

This works:

```
class LoginController: UIViewController {

    init(){
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

        let button = UIBarButtonItem()
        button.title = "Test2"
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button        
    }

    ......

}
```

This doesn't work:

```
class MainNavigationController : UINavigationController{

    private var _distributionProvider : DistributionProvider!

    init(rootViewController: UIViewController, distributionProvider : DistributionProvider) {
        _distributionProvider = distributionProvider
        super.init(rootViewController: rootViewController)

        navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 90/255, green: 177/255, blue: 225/255, alpha: 1)

        let button = UIBarButtonItem()
        button.title = "Test"
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button


    }


   .... 
}
```

Where is problem? Thanks

Comment: Why are you using the init() function?

Comment: I tried viewDidLoad() etc... and same problem :(

Comment: you need to know that `UINavigationController ` is a manager for `viewControllers` it have and show each viewcontroller's navigationItem

Comment: Ok :( I need to add view with username and icon as right barbutton for each viewcontroller

Comment: @JaSHin you can use a base viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

You've to do this:

```
class MainNavigationController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate{
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let item1 = Item1ViewController()
        let icon1 = UITabBarItem(title: "Title", image: UIImage(named: "someImage.png"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "otherImage.png"))
        item1.tabBarItem = icon1
        let controllers = [item1]  //array of the root view controllers displayed by the tab bar interface
        self.viewControllers = controllers
    }

    //Delegate methods
    func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        print("Should select viewController: \(viewController.title) ?")
        return true;
    }

}
```